# show row data from a specific ID

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a simple bug tracking tool.
You can create new projects, when you create a project you have to fill in a form, that form posts to project.class.php (which is this code)

```
$name        = $_POST['name'];
$descr       = $_POST['description'];   
$leader      = $_POST['leader'];    
$email       = $_POST['email'];

$sql="INSERT INTO projects (name, description, leader, email, registration_date)
VALUES ('$name', '$descr', '$leader', '$email', NOW())";

$result = mysql_real_escape_string($sql);
$result = mysql_query($sql); 

if($result){
header('Location: ../projectpage.php?id='.mysql_insert_id());
}
else {
echo "There is something wrong. Try again later.";
}

mysql_close();
```

(It's not yet sql injection prove, far from complete...)

Eventually you get redirected to the unique project page, which is linked to the id that is stored in the MySQL db. I want to show the name of that project on the page, but it always shows the name of the first project in the database.

(here I select the data from the MySQL db.)

```
$query = 'SELECT CONCAT(name) 
AS name FROM projects';

$result = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
$result = mysql_query ($query);
```

(here I show the name of the project on my page, but it's always the name of the first project in the MySQL db)

```
    <?php 
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
        echo '<h5>' . $row['name'] . '</h5>'; 
    ?>
```

How can I show the name of the right project? The one that is linked with the id?
Do I have the use WHERE .... ?

Comment: Yes you have to use where: `WHERE id = ?`

Comment: Do u even have id in your table declaration?

Comment: @Tobias Kun then I always get this error
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: @Flash Thunder yes, I have an ID (with Auto Increment).

Comment: So as someone already have written use `WHERE id = ...`. I would suggest to use $_SESSION to store the id and not to pass it via URL.

Comment: Can you please describe the primary key field name? As in ID, id or project_id or whatever, instead of replying with `expects resource, Boolean given` so folks here can give you the correct where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You have to use the WHERE to specify which project You want to get. I'm also not sure why are You using CONCAT function when You want to get only one project.

Other important thing is that You have to use mysql_real_escape_string() function on parameters **before** You put them in the query string. And use apropriate functions for specific type of data You receive.

So Your statement for getting the project should look like this:

`SELECT name FROM projects WHERE id = ' . intval($_GET['id'])`

Also when before You use the mysql_fetch_assoc() function, check if there are any records in the result with

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
  $project = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  /* $project['name'] */
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting this error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: Check the added part, and also look into Your database that the inserting class is doing everything as expected. Check the proper usage of escaping a query here: [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
// first get the id, if from the url use $_GET['id']
$id = "2";  
$query = "SELECT `name` FROM `projects` WHERE `id`='".intval($id). "'";
$result = mysql_query(mysql_real_escape_string($query));
```

use `mysql_fetch_row`, here you'll not have to loop through each record, just returns single row

```
// if you want to fetch single record from db
// then use mysql_fetch_row()
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
if($row) {
    echo '<h5>'.$row[0].'</h5>';
}
```

`$row[0]` indicates the first field mentioned in your select query, here its `name`

Answer (score -1):

The might be of assistance:

Your are currently assing a query string parameter `projectpage.php?id=`

When you access the page the sql must pick up and filter on the query string parameter like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT CONCAT(name) AS name FROM projects WHERE projectid ='. $_GET["id"];

$result = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
$result = mysql_query ($query);
```

Also maybe move mysql_insert_id() to right after assigning the result just to be safe.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$insertId = mysql_insert_id();
```

Then when you assign it to the querystring just use the parameter and also the

```
header('Location: ../projectpage.php?id='.$insertId);
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: @TobiasKun Yeah I know, I have to make it sql injection prove and should use mysqli... But first I'd like to solve this problem first :).

Comment: Interesting how comments like sql-injection and depreciated sql are thrown in before assisting the OP with a solution.